# How to send input field text to a speech bubble?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, chat, textinput

I'm very new to C# and am trying to generate speech bubbles using text from an input field in Unity. I already have a working speech bubble script that can generate text in quotation marks, however I'd like to use it to pull from a TextMeshPro input field. Here is my "PlayerTalk.cs" script so far:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class PlayerTalk : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField] private Transform playerTransform;

    private InputField ChatInputField;
    private string input;
    private TextMeshPro inputText;

    public void ReadStringInput(string Input)
    {
        input = Input;
        ChatBubble.Create(playerTransform, new Vector3(0, 0), ChatBubble.IconType.Neutral, inputText.text);
    }
}
```

The final field is what I'm concerned with. You can see I'm trying to prompt the Chat Bubble to use text from the "ChatInputField" object. Currently, this script gives me the error : "object reference not set to an instance of an object". If I change the field "inputText.text" to "testing", for example, the script generates a speech bubble saying "testing" when I hit enter on the chat input box in-game. Any help with this is appreciated.

I've tried setting the final input field to various proxies or links to the data from the "ChatInputField" item. This resulted in errors regarding the object reference that I am not sure how to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not referencing an actual TextMeshPro Object, which is why you are getting a reference error. If you provide more information on how you are trying to reference the input field, I'd be glad to help.

Comment: Thanks for your insight, Cynsastic. I am trying to pull whatever text the player has entered into the Input Field - TextMeshPro object "ChatInputField" on the game canvas so that it displays as text inside the ChatBubble.

Comment: I've also tried using "GameObject.Find("ChatInputField").GetComponent<InputField>()" in the code to pull this data but am receiving an error saying : "Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.UI.InputField' to 'string'". Apologies as I am not too familiar with the syntax yet.

Comment: What you need is the Text field of the InputField, not the Instance itself: `GameObject.Find("ChatInputField").GetComponent<InputField>().Text`

Comment: `text` property is lower case (as all public properties in the Unity API) ;)